# Facebook Page Tab Fluid Height

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Basically I want the iFrame that contains my app to expand and shrink as the content changes.

I know this question has been asked a million times but Facebook has changed their JS API a whole bunch and as a result the previous answers to this question no longer work.

I've tried `FB.Canvas.setSize();` as other answers have suggested but to no avail. Does anyone know the method that actually works at this point in time?

My app can be found here for reference: http://www.facebook.com/SandboxAppPage/app_441443775903676

**Edit:** I can't even get a basic skeleton app to behave and resize properly. My basic HTML skeleton (no html, additional js libraries, images, etc) is still fixed at the default 800px height.

Comment: Demonstration site is down..

Comment: Ahhh, I'm a moron, forgot I was working on localhost, should be fixed now.

Comment: Maybe your page resources are not yet fully loaded (e.g. images)? this way you need to make sure that `FB.Canvas.setSize()` is actually called on window onload event. Check out my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/#user_auto-size_option_and) and see if this helps.

Comment: @ifaour it's weird `FB.Canvas.setSize()` doesn't even work when fired on click events (well after everything is loaded). What's even more odd is that I DID get it to resize by accident by having a PHP error on one page which outputted an error message. The error message somehow caused `FB.Canvas.setSize()` to work correctly.

Comment: Not sure it has anything to do with server-side...maybe your HTML is confusing the Facebook `setSize()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/)? It should fix your problem. This function works only when Canvas Height is set to Fixed at 800px in app settings.

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(1000);
```

Here the function will be called in interval of every 1000 milliseconds and resize the window based upon your contents.